# Reading data from ethernet balance (via TCP)

Tags: javascript, tcp, modbus, modbus-tcp

Good morning,
I need to read a weight from a balance connected to the local network.

I explain my case well:
I have a remote server, on which a PHP app is running, usable by the user via browser.
The user has connected a balance to his local network and needs to read the weight from it.
The balance uses TCP protocol.

I tried to use html5 websocket, but I always get an error:
WebSocket connection to 'ws: //192.168.1.205: 23111 /' failed: Invalid HTTP version string: (a small portion of my response string followed)
or sometimes:
WebSocket connection to 'ws: //192.168.1.205: 23111 /' failed: Unexpected response code: 200

How can I solve? Or is there another system other than "websockets" to get data from the client?

**Edit:**

The balance has an rs232 serial port, connected to a device (dini argeo ETHD Module) which converts the signal and makes it "reachable" with the tcp (or udp) protocol to the default port 23 (which I changed to 23111 to avoid problems with the numbering of the ports). In the documentation I read that I can only set the ip of the device, the tcp (or udp) port and it works with modbus mode RTU.

There isn't much else. I put the link to a product configuration video, if it is useful - https://youtube.com/watch?v=P05uiMmaudc .

I also have the manual in Italian: https://sia.solutions/ETHD_03.00_16.06_IT_U.pdf

Comment: I'm sure that the manufacturers of this balance will have provided some documentation that should help. Since you haven't provided us even with the maker's name it's difficult for us to help you.

Comment: `The balance uses TCP protocol` ...ok so what part of that made you think that trying to connect to it via websockets would be likely to work? I think maybe this comes from a lack of understanding of how websockets actually operate. Some [basic research](https://sookocheff.com/post/networking/how-do-websockets-work/) would remedy that for you. (Hint: they are not the same as a simple TCP socket).

Comment: Also, check the manufacturer's documentation for how to actually talk to this device, including connection details and protocol specifics (just knowing it uses TCP sockets is not enough). If it doesn't have a HTTP or WSS interface then it's unlikely you'll be able to connect to it directly from JS running in a browser, which is heavily sandboxed. (P.S. It's unclear how you expect us to know this information, when you haven't provided even the name/ID of the device, let alone any documentation or anything else related. We are not mind-readers :-))

Comment: No, I've never worked with sockets, so I don't know how to do it, so I asked for help.
I was hoping you could read minds :) :) :)

Comment: The balance has an rs232 serial port, connected to a device (dini argeo ETHD Module) which converts the signal and makes it "reachable" with the tcp (or udp) protocol to the default port 23 (which I changed to 23111 to avoid problems with the numbering of the ports).

In the documentation I read that I can only set the ip of the device, the tcp (or udp) port and it works with modbus mode RTU.

There isn't much else.

I put the link to a product configuration video, if it is useful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P05uiMmaudc

Thanks so much!

Comment: Videos are less useful than manuals because it's harder to skip to the bit you really need or skim it for just the crucial information. And videos take far too long because people speak a lot slower than I can read...do you have an actual manual for this thing?

Comment: P.S. all that info should have been in the question from the beginning :-)

Comment: `I've never worked with sockets`...all the more reason to have done some up-front research into sockets and websockets then, before diving straight in.

Comment: Anyway as a broader point you're definitely going to need a native desktop app to interface with the device, it can't be done through a browser directly - you can't make a raw TCP socket connection via browser-based Javascript. The native app can then forward the data to your PHP server via HTTP, if necessary.

Comment: I have the manual in Italian: https://sia.solutions/ETHD_03.00_16.06_IT_U.pdf

Comment: In the manual there is however little, unfortunately, as in the video

Comment: Well the main clue seems to be the modbus protocol. Once you've established the socket connection, that's the format in which you'd send and receive messages from it. I'm not familiar with it personally but it seems to be some sort of open standard from a quick google, so you should be able to find documentation on the protocol definitions, and/or existing client libraries written in common programming languages. I've re-tagged your question as well with relevant tags so someone with direct modbus expertise might see it.

Comment: Thanks, in the meantime I try to do some research.

Comment: One last thing: is there any web language or some totally web (even complex) system to do this, that you know?

Comment: I think I've already covered that? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66902715/reading-data-from-ethernet-balance-via-tcp?noredirect=1#comment118265407_66902715

Comment: According to page 14 of the manual you posted, your product has different working modes. Which one of those have you chosen? The manual is not very clear but it looks like you can choose a Modbus RTU to Modbus TCP bridge. If that's the case you might want to take a look at a [Modbus library for php](https://github.com/aldas/modbus-tcp-client). You should also try to get a Modbus map from the device's manufacturer, explaning which registers you need to read. Everything on their website seems to be available for registered users only...

Comment: @MarcosG. appreciate the input...from the OP's description I think the problem with using PHP for this is that their PHP is server-side on a hosted website, whereas the device is going to be plugged into the end-user's (client-side) device. I guess command-line PHP could be employed, but I'm just dropping this in for clarity for the OP's sake.

Comment: The operating mode is set to "serial to ethernet".
And... yes, @ADyson is right, php on the server, device on the client :(

Comment: sorry but I don't really understand how your setup is supposed to work. Anyway, in that operating mode, your gateway is not acting as a Modbus forwarder so you can forget about what I said before. In my humble opinion, you should try to get another manual from the manufacturer. If you have to go with what you have you can always install the software they show on the video and try to figure out what the protocol looks like using Wireshark. Since I did not understand the client-server part of your question I won't be able to give you much about that. Maybe if you show code or explain more...